# ng-switch is not matching with the expected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I'm having problems with angularjs ng-switch

JS

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentUser = {"userId":"1","userRole":"N"};
    $scope.userRoles = {"normal":"N","admin":"A"}
    $scope.patient = {name: 'John'};
}
```

HTML

```
    <div ng-switch on="currentUser.userRole">
      <a ng-switch-when="userRoles.normal" href="normalUrl"> 
          {{patient.name}} 
      </a>
      <a ng-switch-when="userRoles.admin" href="adminUrl"> 
          {{patient.name}} 
      </a>
      <div ng-switch-default> default </div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

I expect the name of the patient to be displayed with a link to normalUrl but 'default' is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDhM6/) with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngSwitchWhen` directive does not evaluate expressions ([although I've heard this might be added to 1.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5512)). The value is interpolated as a string literal, so you would have to use it like this:

```
<a ng-switch-when="N" href="normalUrl">
```

That will work, but if you really need to dynamically determine your when value, then maybe `ngIf` will better suit your needs:

```
<a ng-if="currentUser.userRole === userRoles.normal" href="normalUrl">

<a ng-if="currentUser.userRole === userRoles.admin" href="adminUrl">
```

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll use ngIf instead. Thanks